# Facebook post recently not showing image, og:image tags correct in debugger

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Over the past few weeks we have been finding that facebook posts (not shares from the in-page FB button) have been failing to show the images tagged with og:image on our site.  Our home page http://www.greatbritishchefs.com is an example.  This seems to be a change in behaviour at Facebook's end because pages which were working a few weeks ago now do not.  Also where a page is working currently, running it through the FB debugger causes it to immediately fail.  Removing the og:image tag does not work.  The images seem to be the right size, and the debugger results are free of errors regarding the image.

Would be grateful for help from anyone who is also experiencing this.

Answer (score 0):

OK I found the resolution to this.  What appears to have happened is that Facebook has become much more demanding about what kind of image urls it will work with in posts.  The images on our site are sourced through a handler which preprocesses the image, putting a watermark on, resizing etc. and therefore the url might look like:

http://www.greatbritishchefs.com/getmedia/0ecdeb1f-c194-42a9-b465-012004a6cd99/AYW001-Website-Edited-Featured-Bacon-Breadsticks-Closeup/?width=420&height=270&ext=.jpg

This will now not work.  For some reason, the url has to be completely vanilla without any query strings and with a standard image extension.  When I rewrite the url for og:image to follow those rules, the images reappear in posts.

Hope this helps someone

James

Comment: You can process jpg extension in your server side language.